# dump file to db using "DB browser for SQLite"

Tags: database, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have a .dump file that contains about 159k of queries to create a database.
I'm new to sqlite3 and using "DB browser for SQLite".
How can I make my database using the dump file?
I didn't find any options in the application...
I did a dummy thing but it didn't work correctly:
I just copied all the queries and executed them in the application.
But only one of the TABLES appears in the db

Comment: Instead of starting with 159,000 queries, start with half a dozen and see if that works.

Comment: @ravenspoint i dont know how to make my db from dump file... independent from the number of queries

Comment: Start with basics.  Create one table and insert one row.